# GCC cross compiler paths

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling

I'm somewhat new to the details of cross compilers and how libraries work, and I have a few questions about building gcc cross compilers, which seem like they should be simple, but I can't find any clear information about this anywhere. They might not all be closely related, but hopefully they can be answered individually:

- How does the new compiler know where to look for the binutils, or for its internal executables, without accidentally using the ones for the host system? Does it use hardcoded absolute paths?
- Why do the configure scripts of both binutils and gcc accept a `--with-lib-path` option? Isn't that only something that `ld`, which is in binutils, needs to know?
- When configuring gcc, what is the `--with-local-prefix` option, and how does it differ from `--with-native-system-header-dir`? Is there any way to fully manually configure what the default include paths are?
- What are the `<prefix>/<target>` and `<prefix>/lib/gcc/<target>` directories exactly? Do they contain libraries for the target architecture? If so:

  - What's the purpose of having them installed in the host system, instead of the target system or a directory that mimics the layout of the target system? It seems like either you would have a new sysroot that you want to install them into, or you have an existing sysroot and should use its existing libraries.
  - How do I install them into a new target system?
  - Is this included in the compiler's search path in addition to the sysroot and `--with-...` options? What if this is not wanted?
- Why isn't it mentioned in the gcc installation instructions how to build and install the gcc compiler, libgcc runtime library, and libstdc++ library separately? Isn't this essential to be able to build and use a cross compiler, or am I missing something?
- What are all the libraries that come with gcc (other than libgcc and libstdc++)? Are they for gcc itself, or are they libraries meant to be installed on the target system for use by applications?

Any good guides or articles that explain this would also be appreciated.